# Retaining a mesh while deleting vertexes

Tags: modeling

So, I want to make a sphere with faces similar to what is seen in the image:[image]

I though I could achieve this by deleting the vertexes in a mesh, while hopefully keeping the sphere shape, but alas, Blender doesn't allow that. Is there something I'm missing or an addon of sorts I can get to help me with this?

Comment: your question is too vague, are you trying to make a sphere or a circle? If this is a sphere, how does it look like on its side or top view? You tried by deleting vertices in a mesh, what vertices and what mesh are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dissolve tool that you may find helpful. When you hit X while selecting an edge loop it will give you the option to dissolve edges, which will remove the vertices but keep the faces as close to intact as possible.